# NullReferenceException was unhandled, Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, exception, reference, null, instance

Whenever I run my program, I get: NullReferenceException was unhandled, Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I start the program, I have a form appear called MaxScore where the user enters the max score and presses OK. In the OK event, I call a method from MainForm to update the maxGameCountLabel on MainForm with the value entered for the max score, as a parameter.

When I press ok, I get the NullReferenceException at

```
myGameCountLbl.Text = maxGames.ToString();
```

of my maxGameCountLblUpdate method.

Here is the maxGameCountLblUpdate method code which resides in MainForm:

```
//Update game count label 
public void maxGameCountLblUpdate(decimal maxGames)
{
    maxGames = decimal.ToInt32(maxGames);
    myGameCountLbl.Text = maxGames.ToString();
    compGameCountLbl.Text = maxGames.ToString();
}
```

Here is my OK Button event on MaxScore:

```
private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm.maxGameCountLblUpdate(max);
}
```

Note, I have set

```
public Form1 MainForm { get; set; }
```

in MaxScore

And I create MaxScore in MainForm with:

```
    using (MaxScore scoreForm = new MaxScore())
    {
        scoreForm.MainForm = this;
        scoreForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I can't get this to work.. I have tried many things.. 
Thanks!

EDIT: After adding a breakpoint at myGameCountLbl.Text = maxGames.ToString();
myGameCountLbl appears to be coming up as null... Im sorry for being a newb... How do I fix this? maxGames, indeed, does come up as 1, so that is not the problem

Comment: Eric - were you calling maxGameCountLblUpdate in the constructor before InitializeComponent()?  I think there was some confusion because your questions makes it look like it was called from the okBtn_Click event.  You can figure it out from the Call Stack which you'll find to be another useful debugging tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remove: `InitializeComponent();` from the constructor?

If you are using the designer to build the form UI, Visual Studio builds a method in the background (Class.designer.cs) to initialize the controls.  If you don't call `InitializeComponent()` before you access the UI elements, you will get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Wow! I had InitializeComponent() after all of my other code... Ahhh! Thank you very much, putting it back at the top fixed it!

Comment: I'd expect the rest of the form not to work in that case, which doesn't sound like the initial description.

Answer (score 4):

Well if this is the line that's causing the problem:

```
myGameCountLbl.Text = maxGames.ToString();
```

then either `myGameCountLbl` is null, or `maxGames` is. Given that `maxGames` is a decimal, that suggests that `myGameCountLbl` is null.

What happens when you debug into this and put a breakpoint on the appropriate line? What does that show for `myGameCountLbl`?

Comment: myGameCountLbl appears to be coming up as null... Im sorry for being a newb... How do I fix this? maxGames, indeed, does come up as 1, so that is not the problem.

Comment: You'll need to initialize it somewhere - exactly where is hard to say without seeing more of your quote. If you're using the UI designer, I'd expect it to be initialized already.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have Visual Studio break on all exceptions, or break on all NullReferenceExceptions, and then you can inspect what's going on.

(Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions ...)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a breakpoint in that line and debug the current state of both objects? Where is max coming from in here?

MainForm.maxGameCountLblUpdate(max);

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted a long time ago but I encountered the same problem and this is how I solved it.

If you look at the troubleshooting tips provided, the second one suggests:

> Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method.

That is actually the solution. Using an IF statement to check if the value to be assigned is not null like:

```
if (maxGames!=null){
      myGameCountLbl.Text = maxGames.ToString();
}
```

That will ensure you avoid assigning null value to myGameCounLbl

I hope that helps

Comment: However, populating your code with masses of ifs is not always the best thing to do. When a value is null is sometime the sign of a major bug in your code. You should handle nulls only when you know that a specific value can be null in a handled case.